# How to do a global override to a method?

Tags: android

I have declared a global boolean variable in my MainActivity class and set its value to true:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public boolean inAppTextIntegration = true;
    //onCreate method and stuff
```

I have 11 more activities in my application. And, in every activity, I'm overriding the attachBaseContext method as:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    if(inAppTextIntegration) {
        super.attachBaseContext(ZeTarget.attachBaseContext(base, this));
    }
    else {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }
}
```

I have declared the boolean variable `inAppTextIntegration` in all my activities. Now the problem part: Since I'm doing the same thing in all the activities, **is it possible to reduce the code**?

Currently, I'm using `SharedPreferences` to store the value of `inAppTextIntegration` in my MainActivity, and then accessing that value in other activities because I don't want to set this value manually in all the activities.

Again, the problem that I face is in all other activities, `else` part of the overriding method is being executed (I'm initializing `inAppTextIntegration` variable in `onCreate` method of all other activities. Doing it outside the onCreate method causes null pointer exception as the context is not set yet).

So, **how do I control the override to `attachBaseContext` at all other activities just by changing one variable in the MainActivity**?

Comment: for the first part, code reduction and factorization, define a superclass that does that and that all your activies extend. For the second part, init the value of your variable directly in `attachBaseContext` since that's where you use it. Use the `base` context to access your prefs

Comment: Thanks for the response. But all my activities already extend AppCompatActivity. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can create a custom class that extends AppCompatActivity and have all your Activities extend your custom class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i)  Create a class which contains all the common methods that all your activities will have.

(ii) Make this class extend `Activity`, `AppCompatActivity` or whatever all your activities are extending.

(iii) Make all your activities extend this class instead of what they are already extending.

You're done :)